# What are the advantages of Hudson vs using a shellscript?

Tags: hudson

What are the "killer-features" of hudson that make using it so much better than using a cronjob for doing nightly builds?

Comment: This is a question for Google and not for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Googled a lot - sorry if this question is beneath your level!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hudson is a complete solution for continuous integration. It comes together with various plugins and features for almost every integration task. Moreover, it provides a flexible and user friendly GUI for monitoring and configuration. Performing CI by means of cronjobs instead of a CI Server is similar to using text editor instead of an IDE.